# How To Combine Multiple Rows Data in A Rows in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one text file which contains 700k entry and the files pattern as below

```
JOB1

JOB Name     : ABC
JOB Region   : Kolkata
JOB Time     : 8.00 PM
JOB Type     : Urgent
JOB Priority : Low

JOB2

JOB Name     : PQR
JOB Region   : Mumbai
JOB Time     : 9.00 PM

JOB3

JOB Name     : XYZ
JOB Time     : 8.00 PM
JOB Type     : Urgent
JOB Priority : Medium
JOB Security : NA
```

Whenever I paste the data in excel it's like below

[image]

But I want to paste the data in excel sheet in below format

[image]

Someone please help me

Comment: Just as clarification, you want to widen column A and remove the empty row below each "JOB X" cell?

Comment: Yes. need to remove the empty row below each "JOB X" cell

Answer (score 0):

Here is one, rather verbose, version:

[image]

Formula in `A23`:

```
=LET(x,SCAN("",A1:A21,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(AND(LEFT(b,3)="JOB",ISNUMBER(--MID(b,4,LEN(b)))),b,a))),DROP(REDUCE(0,UNIQUE(x),LAMBDA(c,d,VSTACK(c,"",d,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,FILTER(A1:A21,(A1:A21<>d)*(A1:A21<>"")*(x=d)))))),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to do that is to replace the new line charachter with ";" and then replace ;; with ; and ; with " " (espace) and apload all that to excel with ; as a delimiter